# Printing arrays of Column Letters, Column Ranges, and Column Numbers (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

[Link to sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jH74KSuKsqUNa9f0NYxAJbfDNdtJd2p03IGepsO51Cc/edit#gid=0)

Trying to print array of column Ranges and Column numbers at the top section of a sheet. As you can see in the picture below, this is a (mostly) working example, but cell `Q11` is blank when it should say `"$R"`

[image: Here is a picture]

Here are the formulas:

Array of Column Letters:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(Address(ROW(E12:12) + 1,COLUMN(E$12:$12),3), $B$5, ""))
```

Array of Entry Cell Ranges (Row After Header):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(D11:11&"$"&$B$5)
```

Array of Partial Column Ranges (From Entry Row to End of Sheet):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(D$10:$10&":"&D$11:$11)
```

Array of Full Column Ranges

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COLUMN(E$12:$12))
```

Array of Column Numbers

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COLUMN(E$12:$12))
```

Comment: not rly sure what is your question... if you type something in Q13 then Q11 will get you what you want

Answer (score 0):

your formula in D11:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D13:13 = "",, 
 SUBSTITUTE(Address(ROW(E13:13) + 1,COLUMN(E$13:$13),3), $B$5, "")))
```

is bound to row 13 via IF statement so to get desired output in Q11 you need to type something in Q13:

[image]